# Getting error "Element type is invalid: expected a string but got object" relating to ExpoRoot

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting the following error

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ExpoRoot`.
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

followed by

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ExpoRoot`.

This error is located at:
    in ExpoRoot
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

when on the home screen of my application. It doesn't happen all the time but only during development when the app refreshes to apply the changes from the code, and also not all the time but like once every 10-20 times that it refreshes. I've looked into the imports/exports on my app and commented out everything so my application is very simple but it is still happening so I guess that they are not the issue.

My code is currently like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
return(
<View>
<Text>test</Text>
</View>
);

}
```

Anyone got any idea what the issue may be?

Comment: Could be a connectivity issue, are you using a real or virtual device? Can you reproduce the issue on both?